# AS3 get Bitmap from Movieclip with Mask

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bitmap, movieclip, bitmapdata

This works:

```
var a:BitmapData = new BitmapData(640,480);
var b:Bitmap = new Bitmap(a);
a.draw(movieClip);
```

This doesn't work:

```
movieClip.mask = movieClipMask;
var a:BitmapData = new BitmapData(640,480);
var b:Bitmap = new Bitmap(a);
a.draw(movieClip);
```

How can I draw just the visible part of a MovieClip (that uses a mask) into my Bitmap?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a new Sprite and add both the MovieClip and its mask to it.  Then draw the parent Sprite.

```
var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
container.addChild (movieClip);
container.addChild (movieClipMask);
movieClip.mask = movieClipMask;

var a:BitmapData = new BitmapData(640,480);
var b:Bitmap = new Bitmap(a);
a.draw(container);
```

Comment: It works, but in final Bitmap: the movieClip position is different. The original I see a parte of the fullMovielip. In the Final Bitmap I see other part (I mean the mask is losing its position)

Comment: The coordinates of both the mc and the mask must of course be relative to the container Sprite. Unless that is not the case, it should look the same.