# AS3 - Fill a MovieClip with a BitmapData

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a MovieClip with an irregular shape and colored with one color, and I want to fill it with a BitmapData. I've tried:

```
var mc : MovieClip = this.getChildByName("mc_test") as MovieClip;
mc.graphics.beginBitmapFill(new BitmapDataFill());
mc.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, mc.width, mc.height);
mc.graphics.endFill();
```

Is there an easy way to apply the BitmapData to the MovieClip?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Bitmap to reference the BitmapData and mask it with your MovieClip as seen here: [AS3 get Bitmap from Movieclip with Mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096504/as3-get-bitmap-from-movieclip-with-mask)